# Everything is messed up on my phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sync, stock-android, google, system-error

I'm using the stock system on my Samsung GS3, and one day the phone just started restarting itself randomly. It might restart itself once or twice a day, and no pattern was observed. Then all in a sudden in one of those weird self-restarting the phone resets itself. All app data are gone but system settings left untouched.

Then comes the waves of error of Google stuff. As soon as you unlock the screen, all sort of errors popped up randomly, like "Google Services Framework has stopped", "Google App has stopped", and "The process com.google.process.gapps has stopped", etc. The Gmail app doesn't load, and you can't view the list of installed apps in the Play Store.

When connected to a PC, with adb it says it's connected, and I can access the system through adb, but I can't use Windows' explorer to navigate the storage system.

I didn't flash any custom OS. I do have root and xposed installed but there is no special action I did that causes this to happen. The syncing of the Google apps are also messed up, and it seems only apps related to Google are having errors.

Without manually resetting (for real) the phone, is there any way to fix this? Once in a while the phone is still resetting itself and this is driving me crazy.

Comment: The reason the system settings are left is because it reverts it like it is a new device. Your Google errors are because of a corrupted GApps package. Reflash GApps. Not being able to navigate through windows explorer, try changing USB connection mode on the GS3. Having the Xposed framework installed opens up all sorts of problems that could rise from compatibility issues. Start by disabling modules, to see if they might be the culprit. If still there uninstall the framework and continue from there. It also could be from an app that has root causing the mischief.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN Thanks for the response. I'll try disabling those modules and see if that helps.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN It seems that there're so many issues to be fixed, and at the end I just decided to backup and do a factory reset. All is good now. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

First turn airplane mode on that should stop all erros google sync alike.

Then go to settings > account > remove google account.

Then go to where you manage your apps and delete all data + cache of every google app (play store google+ google play services etc).

Also look for an option called something "Redefine preferences" sorry my phone is not on English so may be a little different option but with the same meaning do it then reboot your phone and desative airplane mode see if it's all ok.

If you want you can also do an backup via your PC while on airplane mode so if that steps don't help and you really need to reset you will be OK

Comment: Will removing the account also remove my installed apps?

Comment: But this only addresses a portion of the OP's question.

Comment: No all your old apps and pretty much everything will stay you will only delete google synchronized data on your phone ( e.g gmail emails google contacts etc) but will not delete your google account or what is already sync with it and also if that not work you can try to reset all google apps to factory state should be in the same place where you clear data + cache